# paypal ipn takes more than 3 hour or sometime a day to respond

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am using `PayPal express checkout API` to make user subscription.
And i created `IPN` so when user complete subscription process `IPN` set user status=1.

But right now `IPN` takes 3 or more hours to respond. sometime it works quickly but some time takes more time.

User want to activate account immediately after payment complete, but right now it takes more time because of irregular delay in `IPN`. So what should i have to do in this case? I want user to access subscription immediately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method do you use to create a recurring profile? If you want to immediately complete the transaction you must use the paypal express checkout API and method CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. That I mean in my answer below